# Activity в папке androidTest

Tags: android, android-studio, espresso

Пишу тесты для UI в библиотеке `Espresso`. Возник вопрос, имеется ли возможность переноса неких тестовых активити с разметкой в папку `androidTest`, а не `main`. чтобы отделить основной проект от тестовых данных.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось что в `androidTest` перенести тестовые активити нельзя, возникают проблемы с подтягиванием компонентов из разметки. Перенес активити и разметку в папку `debug`, так можно тестовые данные отделить от основного проекта